# Configuring E-mail server to allow review of each outbound email

Tags: email, exchange, smtp

I want to have a separate person reviewing the style of outbound e-mail correspondence sent by new employees. We have an MS Exchange in our organization, but I can look into any e-mail server system that would be able to allow me to implement such a policy.

Basically it even can just be an API way for my software to hook into the process of outbound e-mail dispatching, to allow review and a swift approval for sending process.

How can this be done without writing my own SMTP server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personnel issues cannot be solved with technology, as I'm sure you know. There is no built-in capability of Exchange that allows for some kind of captive waystation where outbound emails are approved or denied. Certainly you can use transport rules that forward emails from certain mailboxes to other mailboxes. You can keep tabs on things that way. However Exchange is a UC platform, not a personnel workflow management system. You'll need third party tools to allow this to happen.

Yes, [Exchange has a rich API and developer platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/aa731543), so I'm sure you could figure something out. However, guidance on developing a tool like this is, in my opinion, beyond the scope of ServerFault. You will need to fundamentally alter the way that Exchange manages the flow of email.

Your best bet is to look for a pre-built tool that allows for this kind of management. However, before you ask "What tool would do this?" you should know that ServerFault frowns on product recommendations and will likely close that question.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this isn't a build-in feature, or some pre-existing functionality that becomes available when Exchange and Sharepoint are used in conjunction for example. It well may have been that case to integrate the document flow and outbound e-mails.